# Does the EcmaScript specification place any constraints on the process model used to implement the runtime?

Tags: javascript

Does the EcmaScript specification place any constraints on the process model used to implement the runtime?

For example, is the event loop required to be on a separate thread from the thread managing the runtime communication with the operating system IO subsystems?

Comment: Please leave a comment explaining your downvotes so that I am able to rectify the issue.

Comment: Explain down votes? Now there's a novel concept… ;-)

Comment: People with rep to burn obviously!

Comment: If you are going to discuss technical details, you probably should separate JavaScript™ (i.e. Mozilla's implementation of ECMAScript for browsers) and the underlying language, ECMAScript. I don't believe Mozilla have published a specification for JavaScript™, though there is various [*other documentation*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) at MDN.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it does not specify anything about those. Runtime communication and IO are not even part of the language, they come as implementation-dependent exotic objects.

The ECMAScript specification does not even use the term "event loop", though it does define [Jobs and Job Queues](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0#sec-jobs-and-job-queues) which work similar. There is no reason however to implement those with multiple threads, after all, JS alone always runs sequentially.

In contrast, the HTML5 spec does define [event loops](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-loops) and even a [process model](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#processing-model-2), but there is no requirement about multithreading either.

Comment: So a vendor could in theory create a JavaScript runtime not following the "standard" event loop with async IO behavior?

Comment: Promises are async, and those need to follow the spec. But yes, you can easily create a JS runtime that does not offer any async IO functions.