# How do .getElementById() and .innerHTML() bridge between HTML and the DOM?

Tags: javascript

I've been writing Javascript for years, but just now realized I don't entirely understand how these "HTML-y" methods actually interact with the DOM.

My assumption is that when HTML is interpreted into the DOM, the browser keeps references as to which HTML element became which DOM node.

So for `.getElementById` when you select an element, the browser returns the relevant node by reference. Why not just do `.getNodeById` then and be more correct?

My assumption is that `.innerHTML` is interpreted by the browser into the DOM at runtime. However, in older browsers like IE7, `.innerHTML` cannot be used to create table nodes. This suggests to me that it was originally intended just to modify the text properties of existing nodes, but then it seems strange that it exists at all, and we don't just use `.innerText`.

I guess I'm just confused by some Javascript history.

Comment: Notice that `innerHTML` is not a method, and no, there are no references from html (which is just a string) to the DOM nodes.

Comment: It's `getElementById` because only *element nodes* can have ids.

Comment: The browser creates a Document Object Model (DOM) from the HTML, that is a tree-like structure that has properties like elements. Elements are also objects with properties of their own, like ID's, and `getElementById` is a method that finds elements based on the ID property. `innerHTML` is just a property on an element that contains the HTML that makes up the element as a string.

Comment: `.innerHTML` was a buggy feature introduced during the first browser war that stayed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the thing is, things like `.innerHTML` and `.getElementById` aren't really JavaScript objects at all. They're what the language specification calls "Host Objects" - it's a form of FFI. What happens when you call `.getElementById` in most browsers is that the string is marshalled from a JS string to a DOM string and then passed to C++ code.

In fact, they're allowed to have pretty much whatever semantics they please - the language makes no guarantees about how they act (this is also true for other DOM objects like timers and XHR).

Comment: Where do you get to know these things? I mean, it's awesome to know the  spec and internals of the language accurately.

Comment: @AmitJoki specifically (pun intended) [in the spec](http://es5.github.io/#x4.3.8), if you search the spec for the term it's there pretty often. A fun fact is that ES5 doesn't even _know_ about threads or async, it's agnostic to that - there is nothing in the language spec about asynchronousity :D (That changes with ES6 and native promises)

Comment: (In fact, [still no threads](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29799133/1048572) in ES6)

Comment: If you want the spec of the methods you mention then you won't find them in the _ES5 spec_ but in _w3's DOM specs_, [`getElementById`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId), [`innerHTML`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Parsing/#widl-Element-innerHTML)

Comment: @Bergi if you're looking for a threading implementation - Nashorn is a good example

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Yeah, sure they exist (in webworkers as well), I just meant to say that they're still foreign and not mentioned in the spec.

Answer (score 0):

well if you really want to know about the internals and want to digg into the deep rabbit hole of rendering engines i'd give you a start by pointing you to certain source files of chromium:

http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink/trunk/Source/core/dom/Element.cpp

you could find stuff like innerHTML and how it actually works in it. (around line 2425)

`.getElementById()` will just resolve to a document element that matches the specified id and will return a reference to it.
its some kind of identifier with prototyped methods, getters and setters to interact with that element. as soon as you interact with methods like innerHTML etc. you will simply tell the engine to execute that action on the element that is referenced inside the element reference.

just digg around inside the source code. you might get a good insight:

http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink/trunk/Source/core/dom/